# /bin/sh: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, docker, alpine-linux

I installed /bin/sh: wkhtmltopdf `/usr/bin/` directory. However when I try to run the program by entering `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` to shell I receive an error `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found`. It works, however, If I enter `sh /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. Why is that and how can I fix it?

The permissions are `ls -l`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 38.0M Nov 22 2016 wkhtmltopdf
```

`type -a wkhtmltopdf :
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Edit:

The OS I use is Alpine Linux

Output of `ldd wkhtmltopdf`:

```
/usr/bin # ldd wkhtmltopdf
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
    /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so => /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so (0x7f8871fec000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 (0x7f8871fe0000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x7f8871fa4000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x7f8871ef3000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x7f8871ee1000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x7f8871dbe000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7f8871da4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f8871c4f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f8871c3b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by wkhtmltopdf)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x7f8871c18000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x7f8871c0f000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1 (0x7f8871c00000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x7f8871bd0000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x7f8871ba9000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x7f8871ba4000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x7f8871b9c000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/libbsd.so.0 (0x7f8871b88000)
```

I installed wkhtmltopdf by running the following commands in Docker:

```
 wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz && \
    tar xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz && \
    mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/ && mv wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

Comment: check the permissions of your file  /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf you probably don't have the executable bit. To change that: chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000       38.0M Nov 22  2016 wkhtmltopdf` I tried that already but it looks like it's not a permissions error

Comment: [How](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/522549/edit) did you install the program?

Comment: Check the output of `ldd wkhtmltopdf` - you're probably missing a library

Comment: Which OS? SELinux or another MAC tool in place? Any messages in syslog?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us the output of running `wkhtmltopdf`. Not `sh wkhtmltopdf` and not `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`, just `wkhtmltopdf`. ii) tell us exactly how you installed it. iii) Show us the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` and iv) the output of `type -a wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: i) the output of /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf is `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found` ii) I already showed it in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by `ldd` output, this `wkhtmltopdf` binary is built against glibc, the [GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/):

```
libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f88720cc000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by wkhtmltopdf)
```

The [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) library implements the C standard library functions, as well as the POSIX API (`libc.so.6`), and the dynamic linker (`ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`). glibc is the most common libc implementation and used by most Linux distributions.

On Alpine Linux, [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/) is used. musl is much more minimalistic in nature and aims for strong POSIX compliance. The library file for musl is `libc.musl-x86_64.so.1`, and the dynamic linker is `ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`. Programs linked against glibc will therefore fail to link against musl libc.

For running glibc programs on Alpine Linux, you're usually required to install glibc, as described [here](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc). In some cases, if only basic glibc compatibility is required, it is enough to install `libc6-compat` which is the musl-glibc compatibility package.

However, a better alternative is installing the corresponding Alpine package, if such is available (to my experience, in most cases, it is). In your case, simply install the [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/community/x86_64/wkhtmltopdf) package (Alpine 3.9+): `apk add wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: Thank you for informative answer. The package for glibc compatibility is `libc6-compat` not `libc6-compact` but I understand the confusion

Comment: @Lau whops - thanks for correcting! Fixed

Comment: Very strange I installed glibc from github, but it still compains `wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` However I can see that `libXrender.so.1` exists

Comment: I also tried to install using `apk add wkhtmltopdf`  but that got a different error `Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c03) with this library (version 0x50c00)
Aborted (core dumped)
`  Seems like I have another package that uses qt? is there a way to figure out which package uses it?

Comment: @Lau for the Qt conflict, a naive way from the top of my head - if you could start from a fresh image then install the required packages one by one (if using a specific base image follow the steps in the Dockerfile), then see which package installs the conflicting Qt - then, remove it if not required